# OPTIONAL MATCH and WHERE in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm struggling to write a cypher-query.

**Graph**

The picutre bellow shows the complete graph. Some movies do not have a stuntman (the graph is fictional).

**Question**

I wanna get ALL ACTORS (and THEIR MOVIES) who never played in a movie with a stuntman. In this case it would be "Johnny Depp"

[image: Complete cypher graph]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work :

```
MATCH (n:Actor)-->(m:Movie)
WHERE NOT (n)-->()<--(:Stuntman)
RETURN n AS actor, collect(m) AS movies
```

Cheers

PS: there is an other solution, but less performant I think :

```
MATCH (n:Actor)-->(m:Movie)
WITH n AS actor, collect(m) AS movies
WHERE all(m IN movies WHERE not (m)<--(:Stuntman))
RETURN actor, movies
```

Comment: Why is `...WHERE NOT (n)-->(m)<--(:Stuntman)...` not working?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will get you going

```
// Find the actors and their movies
MATCH (a:Actor)--(m:Movie)

// where the actor was never in a movie with a stuntman
WHERE NOT (a)-[:ACTS_IN]-(:Movie)-[:ACTS_IN]-(:Stuntman)
RETURN a,m
```